# Using the URI to highlight menu items

Tags: 7, theming, routes, uri

- I have a content type on my site called "Articles".
- I created a view that lists the nodes of this content type.  It's path is "/articles"
- For that view, I created a menu item in my main menu, "Articles".
- I used the pathauto module for all my nodes of this content type to have the path `articles/[node:title]`

My question is, **I want the menu item to remain highlighted if the user is viewing a single article node, or if the user is viewing the view**.

I solved the issue by using `theme_menu_link()` function in my template.php file for my theme (code below).  Being new to the Drupal API, is there a better way to do it?

What I did:

```
function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {

  //Some variables, we're using
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  //#href is an element inside the item
  $the_path = drupal_lookup_path('alias', $element['#href']) ?: $element['#href'];

  //Compare the path to the actual URI (using sub-function), and if they match, then add a new CSS class
  //either: 'uri-active' or 'uri-active-trail'
  switch(mytheme__menu_detect_uri($the_path)) {
    case 1:  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'path-active'; break;
    case -1: $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'path-active-trail'; break;
  }

  //If there are sub-menu items under this, render those too
  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  //Return the output
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}

/**
 * Detect if a given path matches the current URI, as detected
 * from reading the current_path() alias from Drupal
 *
 * @param string $path_to_check  The path to check
 * @param string $check_against  The path to check against (leave blank for current path)
 * @reutrn int   1 = Matches, 0 = No Match, -1 = In Active Path
 */
function mytheme__menu_detect_uri($menu_item_path, $actual_path = NULL)
{
  if (is_null($actual_path))
    $actual_path = drupal_lookup_path('alias', current_path()) ?: current_path();

  //Compare em
  if (strcasecmp($menu_item_path, $actual_path) == 0)
   return 1;
  elseif (strlen($actual_path) > strlen($menu_item_path) && strcasecmp(substr($actual_path, 0, strlen($menu_item_path)), $menu_item_path) == 0)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module allows you to highlight a menu item if certain condition (like a path) has been met.

Answer (score 1):

Context works but is a bit overkill if you only want to highlight the menu items. The [Menu Trail By Path](http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) module does this automatically according to your path aliases. There is also the [Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) module which offers some more functionality and settings.

Answer (score 1):

If this is meant sole for user experience on the website, as far as I know, there's a possibily to do so via CSS. Using [menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module, you can add a class to that particular list item. Then, any view page should have a class for the body element and you can style the right classes for the view, same with the attributes for single article style format.
No need to write a bunch of php code insead of one or two lines via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function MY_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode) {

  // Just make a blog menu item active during viewing blog post detailed page.
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && !empty($node->type) && $node->type == 'blog_post') {
    menu_tree_set_path('main-menu', 'blog');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make any menu active on certain content type use [menu_set_active_item($path)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_item/7.x) function.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode) {

  if ($view_mode == 'full' && !empty($node->type) && $node->type == 'article') {
    menu_set_active_item('[MENU_PATH]');
  }
}
```